# Why will they ask question if Allah knows everything?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, allah, islamic-philosophy

I found this hadith but I'm confused why they will ask question. If Allah(S.W.A) knows everything about us.
This is hadith
"The two angels who are charged with questioning come to him and ask him what he used to believe in in this world, who was his Lord, what was his religion and who was his Prophet.If he gives a good answer, that is good, but if he does not answer them they inflict a severe and painful beating on him. "

Why will someone be punished based upon these questions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you feel when some accusing you doesn’t give you a chance to defend yourself and just gives your sentence?

Allah is playing it kind and fair. He is just. You can’t punish one without setting up a trial. The angels asking is part of his trial.

Our mouth, hands, feet, body talking against us is part of his trial. He doesn’t need it. **We need to see our inability to answer** otherwise we are arrogant and apparently don’t want to be punished or burnt in hell :/And since we aren’t the most humble beings we’d be like *he didn’t give me a chance to defend myself*.

This is all to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Evidence and witness is the main elements of all judical events among people. As the creator of all, Allah puts these kind of events to prevent any objections or doubt to his divine justice. He knows everything yes,but this doesn't mean he intervenes or skips all unnecessary time wasting and cuts to the chase, we're creations of his will and power so at some points he plays with our rules to show his knowledge and might.